# Using urls names in views

Tags: django, django-views

Is it possible to use urls names in views, like we can do it in template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

(Updated answer to point to an existing url.)

Answer (score 12):

Check out the docs on `reverse`

They have a specific example reversing a named url here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

**`reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)`**

> viewname is either the function name
>   (either a function reference, or the
>   string version of the name, if you
>   used that form in urlpatterns) or the
>   URL pattern name.

```
def myview(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('arch-summary', args=[1945]))
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this topic is years old, however during my own search for the same, this one popped up. I believe the requester is looking for the following in views.py:

**views.py**

```
class Overview(ListView):
    model = models.data
    template_name = "overview.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
       name = self.request.resolver_match.url_name
       print(name)
```

Do note that I'm using class based views. Within regular views, the name can be retrieved as follows (not tested):

```
def current_url_name(request):
    html = "<html><body>Url name is {}.</body></html>".format(request.resolver_match.url_name)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

The url name is within the (self.)'request' variable. From within your view, 'resolver_match.url_name' is the one you're looking for.

Hope this helps people in search of the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var salesApiUrl = "{% url 'URLNamesHere' %}"
</script>
```

Now, the salesApiUrl is global. You can use the var name in js as well